laravel stripe Sessionl ID too many characters error, how to solve?
Trying to get the details of a customer's chekout session in Laravel. Below is the pertinent code. Cannot find a relevant cause of this error anywhere.
When dd'ing the $checkout_session variable below, i get the following error:
Invalid string: cs_test_a1...lhMULLaM",; must be at most 66 characters
Code that triggers this:
'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",',

          'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . 'cancel',

        ]);


        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");

        header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);

    }



    // Successful payment

    public function stripe_checkout_success(Request $request) {


        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_API_KEY'));

        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_API_KEY'));


        $session_id = $request->get('session_id');


        $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($session_id);

